# In Subselect, using GetDate instead of a @variable leads to worse execution plan

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

[Execution plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ_lf6Mzg)

This is a simplified version of the real-life problem. When using `GetDate` in subselect, the plan is worse and different. the 2 queries:

```
select * , (select count(1) 
            from hamsfa.customer as sub 
            where sub.tstamp_nosync > @old 
              and sub.cus_id > main.cus_id) as x 
from hamsfa.customer as main ;


select * , (select count(1) 
            from hamsfa.customer as sub 
            where sub.tstamp_nosync > dateadd(year, -100, getdate())
              and sub.cus_id > main.cus_id) as x 
from hamsfa.customer as main ;
```

What I don't fully understand is why.

The variable *should* be by my understanding be worse.

There is another query where this leads to a difference of almost 700% (1s vs 7s).

So the question is: *Why does a variable produce better plan even through it should be worse by my experience?*

EDIT: Statistics are up to date and correct

Comment: Why should a variable be worse? Also add the `CREATE TABLE` statement and the indexes of the table.

Comment: Are you sure that the `and sub.cus_id > main.cus_id` should be like that? And not `and sub.cus_id = main.cus_id`? Looks like a very weird joining condition.

Comment: 1) a variable estimates statistics, in case of datetime at about 30%
2) this example is a simplified thing i am trying to proof, i may be forced to create an obfuscated table and indices (different name, same stuff)
3) condition for cus_id is there to reference the main table

Comment: Yes, that would be better I think. Sometimes simplification makes a question really hard to answer.

Comment: Can you try running the good query with TF 8690 (disables performance spools) enabled? It might give a clue.

Comment: It *might* be due to [unordered prefetch](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/08/31/sql-server-internals-nested-loops-prefetching.aspx) since getdate() or dateadd() is a function. Can you post a repro if possible (use gist and link it here) ?

Answer (score 7):

When you use the variable, SQL Server makes a guess at the selectivity of the  `tstamp_nosync` predicate. For the `>` operator, the guess is 30%. The table contains 3052 rows, so estimation guesses that 30% of 3052 = 915.6 rows will pass that test.

When you use the `dateadd(year, -100, getdate())` expression, SQL Server can produce a much more accurate estimate of the number of rows that will qualify *for that predicate*.

Your build of SQL Server 2012 does not have the [Actual Rows Read property](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/06/sql-indexes/actual-rows-read-warnings-plan-explorer), so the number of rows that actually match is not available in your second plan. That feature was added in Service Pack 3 of SQL Server 2012 (you are still on Service Pack 1, for some reason).

From what I can tell, the better estimate for the `dateadd` expression is that *all* rows will qualify. This is apparent from the output of the Eager Index Spool in the first plan. The 3052 rows are tested 3052 times (once per iteration of the nested loop join) with the `tstamp_nosync` predicate, and all pass. The result is 3052 * 3052 = 9,314,704 rows in total. This is shown as the actual number of rows from the spool:

[image: Eager Spool properties]

The general expectation that using variables will result in a worse execution plan is sound, because specific estimations are usually more accurate than complete guesses; however, the other predicate `sub.cus_id > main.cus_id` in the query will **always** result in a 30% guess.

For the variable query, both predicates are estimated with a 30% guess. The combined estimate is 3052 * 30% * 30% = 274.68 rows (seen at the input to the Stream Aggregate):

[image: Estimated rows from Filter to Stream Aggregate]

For the `dateadd` query, there is one 30% guess (seek predicate) and a 100% selectivity estimate (residual predicate), giving a combined estimate of 915.6 rows as noted previously. This estimate is shown at the output of the Clustered Index Seek:

[image: Clustered Index Seek Properties]

The difference in estimates explains the optimizer's different plan selections.

With fewer rows estimated for the variable case, the estimated cost is lower. The better estimate is costed higher, for similar reasons. Nevertheless, both plans are based on inaccurate estimations because of the guess involved in the `cus_id` predicate.

In terms of *observed* performance, which plan performs better rather depends on the details of your local environment. The variable plan scans the source table once and builds an indexed temporary table in *tempdb*. The non-variable plan simply accesses the base table each time with a seek (guessed 30% selectivity) and residual predicate (computed 100% selectivity). Which performs better in practice depends on multiple factors.

Given correct information for both predicates, the optimizer would be more likely to generate the plan that is better in practice.

It often pays to be very conscious of data types. There is an implicit conversion to `datetime2(4)` in your execution plan because that is the type of the column, and the variable is something else (`datetime` perhaps). The result of the `dateadd` expression is also `datetime`, and also requires implicit conversion. This conversion does not appear to be important in this specific case, but it often is. For example, see:

[Performance Surprises and Assumptions : `DATEADD()`](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-performance/surprises-dateadd) by Aaron Bertrand.

Answer (score 2):

Just an observation. The query seems to be a "triangular" self-join with an extra condition.

It could be rewritten with the self-join in the `FROM` clause or with window functions.

The self-join would mean that the `getdate()` call is not in an inline subquery so it might (not sure and can't test now) avoid the issue, if indeed the issue is caused by the function being in an inline subquery:

```
select *, count(sub.cus_id) as x 
from hamsfa.customer as main
  left join hamsfa.customer as sub 
    on  sub.tstamp_nosync > dateadd(year, -100, getdate())
    and sub.cus_id > main.cus_id 
group by
    main.cus_id, main. ... ;        --- all the table's columns
```

The window function solution will avoid the join altogether and should not face the issue at all:

```
select *, 
       count(case when tstamp_nosync > dateadd(year, -100, getdate()) 
                 then 1 end) 
           over (order by cus_id desc
                 rows between unbounded preceding
                          and 1 preceding)
           as x 
from hamsfa.customer as main ;
```

Comment: thanks, but the point is not to find out HOW to make the query faster, but why using GetDate in subquery causes it to multiply row returned inside the execution plan....

Comment: Yes, I can't answer that, that's why I made the answer CW. A self-join in the FROM clause might solve that issue though, not sure (and can't test right now). added some more details.